# Coffeescript: dynamically create instance of the class a method is called on

Tags: javascript, oop, node.js, inheritance, coffeescript

I am building a Node.js application using object oriented coffeescript.

I have a `super class` with a static method like:

```
class RedisObject
 @find: (id, cb) ->
    client.HGETALL "#{@className()}|#{id}", (err, obj) =>
      unless err
        cb(new RedisObject(obj, false))
```

There is a subclass like

```
  class User extends RedisObject
```

When I call `find()` on the `User class` I want it to pass a instance of `User` instead of `RedisObject` to the callback function.

I tried to realize this by getting the class name of the actual class the method is called on by using

```
@constructor.name
```

and use `eval()` to generate an instance from it - but the problem is that the subclass will be undefined from within the superclass.

How can I realize the behaviour of getting different types of instances returned by the `find` method depending on which class it is called on, without having to override it in each subclass?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'm not an expert in CoffeeScript, but wouldn't this work?

```
class RedisObject
  whoami: () -> "I am a RedisObject"
  @find: () ->
    new this()

class User extends RedisObject
  whoami: () -> "I am a User"

console.log RedisObject.find().whoami() // -> "I am a RedisObject"
console.log User.find().whoami()        // -> "I am a User"
```

At least the above test seems to pass.

Comment: Btw, the "new this" is not documented feature, I can't find it from the Classes section. It's really useful, it should be specced.

Answer (score 0):

```
@find: (id, cb,klass=RedisObject) ->
    client.HGETALL "#{@className()}|#{id}", (err, obj) =>
      unless err
        cb(new klass(obj, false))
```

and in the sub class

```
@find: (id, cb,klass=User) ->
    super(id,cd,klass)
```

that's what i would do though it is not 100% dynamic.